# How To Generate RSAPublicKey with Keys Of Cognito

Tags: java, amazon-cognito

I need to generate a public key to verify JWT token from Cognito. Here are the keys:

```
{
  keys: [
    {
      alg: "RS256",
      e: "AQAB",
      kid: "7sbG73+G/8A+wPT4Vaf/+ttnBHuLZcjEmfiBXl3E8Fk=",
      kty: "RSA",
      n: "blablablablabla",
      use: "sig"
    },
    {
      alg: "RS256",
      e: "AQAB",
      kid: "Zbf1euSHNj4lXgXHIQwYZfERTdm1Rkeqrm1ppnpClRR=",
      kty: "RSA",
      n: "blablablablabla",
      use: "sig"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can easily create it with x5c key from Azure, but i can't do that with Cognito. Which key should i use to create a RSAPublicKey?

```
 CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

//Creating a cert from x5c key   
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(x5c)));

RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) cert.getPublicKey();
RSAPrivateKey privateKey = null;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution in auth0 library.

```
 String keyUrl = "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_xxxxxx/.well-known/jwks.json";
 JwkProvider provider = new UrlJwkProvider(new URL(keyUrl));
 Jwk jwk = provider.get(kid);
 RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey();
```

Comment: do you have sample for python ?